# How can I disable duplicate preview buttons on grapesjs toolbar?

Tags: grapesjs

I have a [grapesjs](https://grapesjs.com/docs/#what-is-grapesjs) editor that is working perfectly. However, because I am using multiple plugins, I am duplicate preview buttons.

Here is a snippet of my initializaion:

```
editor = grapesjs.init({
    container: '#my-element',
    fromElement: 1,
    showOffsets: 1,
    allowScripts: 1,
    plugins: ['gjs-preset-webpage', 'gjs-preset-newsletter'],
    ...
```

I have attached a screen of what I am seeing. As you'll notice, there are duplicate "preview" buttons. If I remove a plugin, only one set of icons will appear (as expected).

This is not correct, but was trying something along these lines to see if I could *remove* the buttons manually.

```
editor.Panels.removeButton('preview', [{
        // 
    }]
);
```

Thank you for any suggestions.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can remove duplicate buttons as mentioned below. the first parameter is the pane
editor.Panels.removeButton('devices-c', 'block-editor');